# classifier using boolean formula

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to find a classifier that is represented by an arbitrary boolean formula.  Is it possible to do so ?  I tried using the SVC from sklearn.svm using the `linear` kernel, but not sure if it is correct and if it is, how to extract a formula from the learned classifier.

Here's a simple dataset with 4 variables `x,y,z,w` (features) and labels `0 and 1`. And any data with `x=1 or y=1` will have a label `1` and everything else has label `0`.

```
x,y,z,w,label
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
0,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,1
0,1,0,0,0
0,1,0,1,0
0,1,1,0,1
0,1,1,1,1
1,0,0,0,1
1,0,0,1,1
1,0,1,0,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,1,0,0,1
1,1,0,1,1
1,1,1,0,1
1,1,1,1,1
```

For this example, I want to extract the classifier represented by the formula `x=1 or z=1`.  Eventually I will have more complex data represented by complex, arbitrary formula (e.g.,  `(x= 1 or y=0) and (z=0) ...` )

Comment: You are basically looking to simplify a boolean function. Have you looked that up, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324804/algorithm-minimizing-boolean-expressions

Comment: Also, please provide a minimal piece of code that shows how you use SVC here.

Comment: @InonPeled:  for this example it looks like I want to simplify boolean formula because I have the complete set of data. However, I will not always have complete data and so actually want to learn some (potentially inaccurate) formula through a classifier.

I was experimenting with
```
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    sv_classifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
    sv_classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```
but after playing more with this today, I think decision tree classifier is what I want.  Because some formula cannot be represented using linear equation given by `SVC(kernel=linear)`

Comment: It is indeed difficult to derive a boolean formula from a fit SVC model with linear kernel. It may be that the problem you are dealing with is nevertheless NP-hard, so that you will have to resort to essentially heuristics. Would be interesting to hear about your results with other classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The input->output relationships in your data is non-linear, discrete and non-smooth. Any linear models will perform badly in this case. Try instead a DecisionTreeClassifier, which should be OK for your kind of data.
Alternatively you could use a Boolean Satisfiability solver, but this will only work if your data is deterministic and not fuzzy.